How to set default filter for a particular column before data load in ag-grid?
I have ag-grid implemented in React.js. I want to apply a default filter for one column(for certain conditions) and then fetch data for ag-grid.
I tried onFirstDataRendered and onGridReady. But those are applying only after the grid is loaded
